# Configuring itemize for itemsep in tex4ht using \ConfigureList

Tags: itemize, tex4ht

The problem is to adjust vertical space for items in itemize list.

```
\begin{itemize}\itemsep2em
\item first 
\item second 
\end{itemize}
```

This works in LaTex but not in html produced by using tex4ht. What should be  configuration to be added in preamble, for example using `\ConfigureList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tex4ht` is focused more on logical markup than on exactly the same look in `pdf` and `html`. In this case, I would define new environment, which can be then configured for `tex4ht` and the vertical spacing can be defined using `CSS`. Sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{mydefinitions}
\begin{document}    
\begin{myitemize}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

Custom environment, `myitemize`, is used. It is defined in package `mydefinitions.sty`:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mydefinitions}

\newenvironment{myitemize}{\itemize\itemsep2em}{\enditemize}

\endinput
```

It can be configured using `\ConfigureList`. We may put the configuration if file `mydefinitions.4ht`:

```
\ConfigureList{myitemize}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<ul class="myitemize">}\ShowPar\bgroup\def\finli{}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\finli\egroup\HCode{</ul>}}
{\ShowPar\finli\HCode{<li>}\par\def\finli{\EndP\HCode{</li>}}\DeleteMark}{}

\Css{.myitemize li + li{margin-top: 2em;}}
```

It looks little bit complicated, but it really isn't, the problem we need to solve are paragraphs, so these are all the `\EndP`, `\ShowPar` and `\IgnorePar` commands. The most interesting stuff happens in the fourth parameter:

```
{\ShowPar\finli\HCode{<li>}\par\def\finli{\EndP\HCode{</li>}}\DeleteMark}
```

It is inserted at the beginning of each item. `\finli` command is used to insert the closing tag for `<li>` element. It is empty by default, so it isn't inserted in the first item. `\DeleteMark` is used for removing of the "■" character, which is inserted by LaTeX.

The `\Css` command states that second and following items should have `2em` space above.

The resulting `HTML`:

```xml
 <ul class="myitemize"><li>
 <!--l. 9--><p class="noindent" >
 first
 </p></li><li>
 <!--l. 10--><p class="noindent" >
 second</p></li></ul>
```

and rendered page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and precise reply. It works like charm...!